# What type of project to create for the shared/core code?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm just starting out using Xamarin so apologies if this is a very very basic question. I searched around but I couldn't find the information I need.

I've created a blank solution and I've added an Android and an iPhone project to this solution. Both apps/projects build and run okay. Now I want to add a third project which will hold the common code for the two apps.

When I right-click my solution and open up the 'Add new project' window, what project type should I choose for this shared/core code project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to use a [Portable Class Library](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/).

Comment: Check out this project https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyExpenses for a good example.

Comment: Jason, I'm unable to add a Portable Class Library project to my solution which I can link to from my Android and iPhone applications. See this other Stack Overflow question I created which explains the problem in a bit more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866946

Comment: I would probably try reinstalling everything to be sure you have a complete install.

Comment: @AdilHussain Make sure to use `Profile158`

Comment: I installed the current MDK and that fixed it. No need to uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the MVVMCross framework,

I've started using it recently and its fantastic.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross