# Portable Class Library project - reference assemblies not installed?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Studio Version 4.2.3 on a Mac (Starter Edition; Mono 3.2.6; Xamarin.Android Version 4.12.1; Xamarin.iOS Version 7.2.02).

I created a blank solution. I added an Android application project and an iPhone application project. Both build and run okay. Now I've added a *Portable Class Library* project which I want to link to from my application projects. However! My *Portable Class Library* project is showing up an error in my *References* folder for the *.NET Portable Subset* reference, as follows:

> Framework not installed: .NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile136

How do I resolve this??

Additionally, when I open the *Project Options* window and navigate to the *General* section, the only Target Frameworks listed are:

- *.NET Framework 4*,
- *Silverlight 4*,
- *Windows Phone 7*,
- *Xbox 360*.

No *Xamarin.Android* and no *Xamarin.iOS*...

Comment: Please specify if this is on Mac or Windows.

Comment: Mac. I've added that to my question as well. Thanks.

Comment: Starter, Indie, Business, Enterprise?

Comment: Starter. (Added that to my question too.)

Comment: I would uninstall everything and then reinstall. If that doesn't fix it, then this is a question more suited for xamarin themselves and not stackoverlow. Either hello@xamarin.com or support@xamarin.com. Or maybe you can email them first, but (having done that myself several times) you will need to send them all of the information you provided here except copy and paste the whole details and not just the version number.

Comment: Thanks for the help valdetero. I'll send Xamarin an email about this. Uninstalling and re-installing seems quite drastic given that I only just installed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the MDK (whatever that is??) from the following directory...

http://download.xamarin.com/MonoFrameworkMDK/Macx86/MonoFramework-MDK-3.2.6.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg

... and that fixed things for me. No need for an uninstall and reinstall of my Xamarin setup.

Note that I had to quit and restart Xamarin Studio for the change to take effect. I also restarted my Mac for good measure!

Comment: Do not blindly download this MDK as it is not compatible with the latest Xamarin. Get the latest Mono MDK from: http://www.mono-project.com/download/

Answer (score 3):

Please check you have the Mono MDK, not the MRE.

Comment: Anubhav, how do I check this?

Comment: Sorry @AdilHussain was not in touch of internet so couldn't reply. Anyways I see that you have already got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I don't have Xbox as an option on my Mac. I have it as an option on Windows (Xamarin Studio & Visual Studio). What edition of Xamarin do you have installed?

[image: PCL Options]

Maybe you need to reinstall it?

My machine:

=== Xamarin Studio ===
Version 4.2.3 (build 60)
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.6 ((no/9b58377)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 theme: Raleigh
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 302060000

=== Apple Developer Tools ===
Xcode 5.1 (5084)

=== Xamarin.iOS ===
Version: 7.2.0.2 (Business Edition)
Hash: 58c3efa

=== Xamarin.Android ===
Version: 4.12.1 (Business Edition)

=== Xamarin.Mac ===
Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed

Comment: valdetero, I installed Xamarin for the first time just a couple of days ago so it must be the latest version? How can I check what version of Xamarin I have?

Comment: Xamarin Studio -> About -> Show Details.

Comment: Thanks valdetero. I've added versioning information to my question.

Comment: valdetero, your versioning is identical to mine other than that I'm using the Starter Edition and you're using the Business Edition.